# Is this possible to let GDB recognise preprocessor symbols?

Tags: c, gdb

I have lots and lots of C preprocessor `#define` statements, which make my C programming much easier. However, when debugging with GDB, the preprocessor "labels" are not accounted for in the symbols list.

Is there are way to have GDB recognise the `#define`d labels?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try compiling with g3, as described [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html).

```
gcc -gdwarf-2 -g3
```

> We pass the -gdwarf-2 and -g3 flags to ensure the compiler includes
>   information about preprocessor macros in the debugging information.

Or you can try `-ggdb`.

Comment: `-ggdb` has no effect. See [Interpret object causing crash in __cxa_finalize](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2011-08/msg00109.html) (I'm pretty sure Jan is one of the GDB developers).

Answer (score 3):

`#define` symbols are not usually included as part of the debug information. `const` variables (or [inline functions for function-like macros](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-vs-macros)) are usually a better idea, and for more reasons than this (e.g., scoping, type safety, multiple evaluations, etc.). I recommend using them in favor of preprocessor symbols whenever you can.

Comment: +1 for favoring `const`, though I wouldn't call them "`const` variables" ;)

Comment: Your answer still assumes only one kind of `#define`, namely one defining a constant. Many others are possible, e.g. `#define min(a,b) ((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b)`.